# Why does everyone copy the src of app in the php-fpm and nginx containers?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, containers

I make an app in PHP(Laravel) that runs in an old virtual server. My idea is to move the app to containers.
I read a lot of tutorials, and all create three containers.

- nginx(as a dispacher)
- php-fpm
- db

its ok, but I still don't understand this.

If the Nginx is only to pass the request to the php-server, why have the app source?

tkx

Comment: What tutorial or guide did you follow that instructed you to make 3 separate containers? For simple web-applications with their own database you only need a single container.

Comment: i want to separate into containers because i need the scale out aproach